# Typescript with require config

Tags: typescript

I am building a web application in which the development isn't built on TypeScript, however the application has integration point which I want to do with plugin style - and this is where TypeScript is used. the TypeScript code is in second solution where I copy the js files to a folder in the first solution. I am using require to load everything. I have a problem of the path of the files in TypeScript. I have created require config

```
require.config({
paths: {
    VideoProviderCommon: 'Scripts/VideoProvider/VideoProviderCommon',
    VideoProviderManagerFactory: 'Scripts/VideoProvider/VideoProviderManagerFactory',
    VideoProviderManager: 'Scripts/VideoProvider/VideoProviderManager'
},
shim: {
    'VideoProviderCommon': { 'exports': 'VideoProviderCommon' },
    'VideoProviderManagerFactory': { 'exports': 'VideoProviderManagerFactory' },
    'VideoProviderManager': { 'exports': 'VideoProviderManager' }
}
```

});

and I want that the js files will have in the define - the module name as configured and not the path, how ever I cannot compile the TypeScript project cause I get compile errors
in

```
import common = require("VideoProviderCommon");
```

for example - as it cannot find the module although I have require config

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
     .....
  var videoWorkItem = (function () {
    function videoWorkItem() {
    }
    return videoWorkItem;
})();
exports.videoWorkItem = videoWorkItem;
```

});

Comment: Is VideoProviderCommon a JavaScript file, a TypeScript class in the same project, or a TypeScript class in another project?

Comment: every thing is typescript - the issue is that i dont want the on the dependency i will have the the absolute path but just the name of the file

Comment: What does the declaration file generated for VideoProviderCommon look like?  With that I should be able to tell you what needs to happen to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I created an additional typescript file to Setup the config and included it after the require.js file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    <script data-main="Scripts/main" src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/config.js"></script>
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

*index.html*

In `config.ts`:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "Scripts",
    paths: {
        jquery: "jquery-1.10.2"
    }
});
```

*config.ts*

after that i was able to just use jquery like so:

```
import $ = require("jquery");
$(() => {
    alert("Hello world!");
});
```

*main.ts*

Note: i got all typings for require, jquery etc. through NuGet

Comment: NB. That you really do actually need require.d.ts for this to work, other wise the inbuilt 'require' keyword will be invoked resulting in the above not working *at all*. See https://github.com/jbaldwin/require.d.ts/blob/master/require.d.ts (NB. the very bottom of the file redefines require)

Comment: Are you sure about that? By the way whats the meaning of "NB", never seen that abbreviation before?

Comment: I don't believe it works; it certainly doesn't when I try it (the generated .js file has the config *inside* the require call, making it useless). NB means 'note well'. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NB It's like, FYI. --> https://gist.github.com/shadowmint/10609103

Comment: I just tried it again, and for me that does work. but i only have the config call in that single config.ts file. For me no surrounding require call gets generated. Leaving me with just that in the generated .js file: `requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "Scripts",
    paths: {
        jquery: "jquery"
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=config.js.map
`

Comment: If you don't call require, how is your main.ts ever imported? It won't be unless you have another external script src="main.js", which breaks the point of using requirejs in the first place. Anyway, if it works for you great; but I'm pretty sure in general this solution *doesn't work* as it currently stands.

Comment: This imports it: data-main="Scripts/main". Please review my code again, also see this http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#add

Answer (score 0):

to import JS files into your typescript files you have two options. Either define the external module youself e.g:

```
declare module "VideoProviderCommon"{
    var foo:any;
    export = foo;
}
```

or use the `amd-dependency` flag as covered in : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AGQpv0MKsA&hd=1